# AWS CloudWatch: How to pass Media convert logs to lamda function in cloudwatch rules?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am trying to setup Video Streaming architecture using AWS S3, CloudWatch and MediaConvert. I am following this link [enter link description here](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-media-services-vod-automation/blob/master/MediaConvert-WorkflowWatchFolderAndNotification/README-tutorial.md) as reference to setup the architecture.

In short the steps are

1. Upload video to S3 bucket
2. On Success S3 should trigger Lambda function which coverts input video
   into different formats and save them in another S3 bucket and logs
   in CloudWatch
3. In CloudWatch based on event pattern trigger another Lambda function
   with the video file information
4. Lambda function will save this information in desired location.

I am stuck in step 3 where I am able to trigger Lambda function but I couldn't able to understand how to pass converted video filepath or filename to lambda function in the target section.

Here is the custom event pattern to recognise media convert success event

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.mediaconvert"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "MediaConvert Job State Change"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "status": [
      "COMPLETE",
      "ERROR"
    ],
    "userMetadata": {
      "application": [
        "VOD"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be creating a cloudwatch [event rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Rule.html) to handle this scenario.
steps for your case-

1. go to cloudwatch/Rules
2. Event Pattern
3. Events by service
4. Select Service Name
5. Select Event Type

This should trigger a cloudwatch event and you need to process that event to get required information.

Comment: Hi, I already did what you mentioned and able to trigger the cloudwatch event. You can see in question that I am using a custom event pattern to recognise cloudwatch event, and able to trigger a lambda function. The problem is how do I pass information(file name in this case) to the lambda function?

Comment: I am presuming that you are looking for converted file? If it is converted file and cw rule has been setup it should give you that information.

However if you want to explicitly know the file name keep a metadata file in S3 and update this metadata file with media converted file and read the same metadata post the cw event.